# Spring MVC 3.1 How to access HttpSession in Custom Authentication Provider (which implements AuthenticationProvider)

Tags: authentication, spring-mvc

My application calls a web service during the Authentication process (as shown in code below).

How can I save some information in HttpSession during this process?
This information like customer-account-number will be used in various other places in the application after the user is logged in.
Is it possible to pass HttpSession parameter to the MyServiceManager's static login method?

```
 public class MyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
                    //MyServiceManager.login - makes a call to web service
        if(MyServiceManager.login(authentication.getName(),     authentication.getCredentials().toString(), XXX_HTTP_SESSION_XXX))
        {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>  ();  
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_SUPERVISOR"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(),authorities);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After breaking a lot of head on this issue, I was able to achive the objective using following work around.
Getting hold of session is really not feasible in following method
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)

I created a class

```
import java.security.Principal;

public class UserInfo implements Principal{

private String customerId;
private String accountNumber;
private String name;
}
```

The information which I wanted to store in session (like customerId, accountNumber etc), I saved it in userInfo object.
and this object was passed to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();  
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_SUPERVISOR"));
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(**userInfo**, authentication.getCredentials(),authorities);
```

This information is readily available in the user's session using

```
(UserInfo)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I home this is a good enough way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session= attr.getRequest().getSession(false);
```

I recommend false as it is assumed that no one without valid session should be inside this method.